# Rotate Widget When Orientation Changes in Flutter (But Keeping The Layout Position)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a camera app which naturally needs to support both Portrait and Landscape orientation.

Is it possible to rotate the widgets without changing the widget layout position? (They are still in place, but the icons are rotated according to the current  orientation, just like a regular camera app behaviour)

Any ideas please?

**PORTRAIT**
[image: PORTRAIT LAYOUT]

**LANDSCAPE**
[image: LANDSCAPE LAYOUT]

**LANDSCAPE**
[image: LANDSCAPE LAYOUT EXPLANATION]

Comment: You can use an `OrientationBuilder` to handle the change. I'm not sure what you mean by "without changing the widget layout position", but you could probably construct your layout in a way that gives the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately flutter doesn't detect orientation side like **portrait up** or **portrait down**

so we will need a package to help to achieve this behaviour [native_device_orientation](https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation)

1- you need to lock screen orientation to `portraitUp` 
2- now we should depend on the **sensor data** to get the device correct orientation without rotating the app. [native_device_orientation](https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation) will help us achieve that 
3- using [RotatedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html) or [Transform.rotate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.rotate.html) to react to current screen orientation as you like

Complete working example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:native_device_orientation/native_device_orientation.dart';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]); // -->[1]
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: NativeDeviceOrientationReader(
          useSensor: true, // --> [2]
          builder: (ctx) {
            final orientation = NativeDeviceOrientationReader.orientation(ctx);
            int turns = 0;
            switch (orientation) {
              case NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitUp:
                turns = 0;
                break;
              case NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitDown:
                turns = 2;
                break;
              case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:
                turns = 1;
                break;
              case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight:
                turns = 3;
                break;
              case NativeDeviceOrientation.unknown:
                turns = 0;
                break;
            }
            // --> [3]
            return RotatedBox( 
              quarterTurns: turns,
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.abc,
                size: 100,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```